# Reason for installation through Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a technical reason, why a Google Drive application must be installed through the Chrome Web Store (which severely limits the number of potential users)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that installation is required is to give users the ability to access applications from within the Google Drive user interface.  Without installation, users would have no starting point for most applications, as they would not be able to start at a specific file, and then choose an application.

That said, I realize it can be difficult to work with in early development.  We (the Google Drive team) are evaluating if we should remove this requirement or not.  I suspect we'll have a final answer/solution in the next few weeks.

**Update:** We have removed the installation requirement.  Chrome Web Store installation is no longer required for an app to work with a user's Drive transparently, but it is still required to take advantage of Google Drive UI integrations.

Answer (score 3):

To provide the create->xxx behaviour that makes a new application document from the drive interface, and to be able to open existing documents from links, there must be some kind of manifest registered with Google's systems and some kind of agreement from the user that an application can access your documents and work with specific file types. There's little way around this when you think about the effects of not doing this.

That said, there are two high level issues that make for compatibility problems.

As the poster says, the requirement to install in the chrome store

> severely limits the number of potential users.

But why? Why do the majority of Chrome Web Store applications say that they only work on Chrome? Most of these are wrappers to web applications that work on a range of browsers, yet you click through a selection and most display "works on chrome", aka only installs on chrome.

Before we launched our application on chrome we found that someone had created "xxxxxxx launcher" in the store, that simply forwards to our web app page. We're still wondering why it only "works on chrome". I suspect that some default template for the web store has:

```
"container" : "CHROME",
```

in it, which is the configuration option to say chrome only. That said, I can't find one, so I'm very confused why this is. It would be healthier if people picked Chrome because it's the better browser (which it is in a number of regards), not because their choice is limited if they don't. People can always write to the application vendor and ask if this limitation is really necessary.

The second thought is that a standardised manifest format across cloud storage providers would mean a much higher take up in web app vendors. Although, it isn't hugely complex to integrate, for example, with Google Drive, the back-end and ironing out the the details took over a week in total. Multiply that lots of storage providers and you have you lose an engineer for 2 months + the maintenance afterwards. The more than is common across vendor integration, the more likely it is to happen.

And while I'm on it, a JavaScript widget for opening and saving (I know Google have opening) by each cloud storage provider would improve integration by web app vendors. We should be using one storage providers across multiple applications, not one web application across multiple storage providers, the file UI should be common to the storage provider.

Answer (score -2):

In order to sync with the local file system, one would need to install a browser plug-in in order to bridge the Web with the local computer. By default, Web applications don't have file I/O permissions on the user's hard drive for security reasons. Browser extensions, on the other hand, do not suffer from this limitation as it's assumed that when you, the user, give an application permission to be installed on your computer, you give it permissions to access more resources on the local computer.

Considering the add-on architectures for different browsers are different, Google first decided to build this application for their platform first. You can also find [Google Drive in the Android/Play marketplace](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&hl=en), one of Google's other app marketplaces.

In the future, if Google Drive is successful, there may very well be add-ons created for Firefox and Internet Explorer, but this of course has yet to be done and depends on whether or not Google either releases the API's to the public or internally makes a decision to develop add-ons for other browsers as well.

Comment: I was looking on Google Drive from the view of a pure web application, which does not need the local storage aspect. But even for a pure web application Chrome Web Store installation is required (according to docs)

Comment: A colleague was telling me that Google Drive syncs with his hard drive. It's not possible for a standalone application to do this. While plain Web apps can of course be installed in Chrome, those plain Web applications have no ability to access anything on the local computer. Aside from that, if there is a Chrome App for Drive that just exposes a Web based UI panel, Google's decision for using the Chrome store may be just simply a way to make it easier for them to market the product or make it easier to keep people logged into it. For more information, I'd suggest contacting a Google employee.