# Application to write files to our customers' google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

We have read other posts where it is said that for us to store a file in a google drive, the client must install a web app form the Chrome Store. But the fact is that we do not need a Web App and do not want to have our customers install a "non-app" just to get access to their drives. We have found suggestions to use the Document List API but we do not find it in the API Console as it has been deprecated.
The error we get is:
"googleapi: Error 403: The authenticated user has not installed the app with client id XXXXX"

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this question for the reason behind the installation requirement: [Reason for installation through Chrome Web Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474588/reason-for-installation-through-chrome-web-store).

And stay tuned for announcements very soon!

Comment: You made me curious - it's probably good I am at #io12 this week? :-)

Comment: Is "very soon" measured in hours, days or weeks...? The files we want to place in google drive are PDF files. So the user does not need our application for using them. Hopefully this requirement will be dropped. Thanks!