# Integrating with google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to integrate with google drive, so that my app can be launched from google drive with "Open With...". I believe I have followed the documentation. I have published my app to test users.. at some point google drive asked for permission to add my app to google drive.

But my app is not displayed in "open with.." or "create new..."

One difference I have seen between my app and other apps that do work is that on this page:

https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en

The apps that work have: "By file Drive API" next to them

and my app says "Disk API"

This is my manifest

```
{
    "name": [hidden],
    "description": [hidden],
    "version": "0.0.0.2",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "container":  "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "api_console_project_id" : [hidden],

    "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
    },

    "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://www.trainyourvision.org/"
    ],

    "launch": {
        "web_url": "http://www.trainyourvision.org/painter/"
        }
    },

    "gdrive_mime_types": {
        "http://drive.google.com/intents/opendrivedoc": [
        { 
            "type": ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.png",
            "application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.jpg","application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.gif",
            "application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.psd"
            ],
            "href": "http://www.trainyourvision.org/painter/",
            "title" : "Open",
            "disposition" : "window"
            }
        ]
    },

    "requirements": {
        "3D": {
        "features": ["webgl"]
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure your app in the Drive SDK tab of the APIs Console? https://developers.google.com/drive/enable-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your app installed to be able to see it in "Create" and "Open With" menus.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474588/reason-for-installation-through-chrome-web-store).
You can do it in two ways :

1. Install it from Chrome Web Store
2. Add install scope to the authorization code request

I prefer the second method. That way when users are prompted to give access to your app they will also automatically install it without having to go to the Chrome Web Store.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes) for scopes .